# Watch a spreadsheet for changes using a Google service account?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a service account that I can use to access data from a spreadsheet:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY, scopes=SCOPES)        
        service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()
```

I want to be able to watch the spreadsheet and be alerted when there are changes.
[The Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) suggests that I need to use a direct HTTP request to do this like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myFilesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

How can I get the auth token to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use HTTP Request, 
All you have to do is open target google spreadsheet, 
tools/utils -> **script editor**

In google apps script, you can set a trigger for changes in spreadsheet. [image: click that lil timer icon right below the menu]

Also, refer this docs to write a .gs file to decide what to do when change occurs(script is triggered)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app